# Output Variable Price appropriately

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In a WooCommerce loop there is the

`<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>`,

that outputs the regular price or the "From" price of a variable product.

However with variable products I need something that I can control. I'll be looping only variable products all with the same attributes, and I want the price tag set to one variation of them.

For example: The price tag shouldn't output the cheapest variation, but the price when the attribute "color" is set to "red" and the attribute "size" is set to "Large".

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all variations and loop throu them. You have available function like -

```
global $product;
if ($product->product_type=='variable') {
    print_r($product->get_available_variations());
    print_r($product->get_variation_attributes());
    print_r($product->get_variation_default_attributes());
}
```

If you want to do it on client side then there are a lot of events that you can hook into. For example.

```
.on('found_variation')
```